# How to put a pstricks figure inside of a tabular environment

Tags: tables, pstricks, pstricks-add

I'm writing a document where I need to build a table and put some figures inside. I use pstricks for my figures as I'm most familiar with it. However this is my first time using tables in LaTeX.

So I tried the following code but got an error from the compiler saying there's probably a missing `\item` :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\definecolor{rouge}{rgb}{0.93,0.11,0.14}
\definecolor{vert}{rgb}{0.22,0.71,0.29}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
        \hline
            $\varphi$ &
            \textbf{Chronogrames} &
            \textbf{Lissajous (XY)} \\
        \hline
            $0$ &
            \begin{center} % Compiler does not like this line
                \psset{xunit=0.5, yunit=0.5}
                \begin{pspicture}(-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)
                    \psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)[$t$,0][$ $,0]
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=rouge, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{2.5*cos(x)}
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=vert, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{1.5*cos(x)}
                    \psline[linecolor=rouge]{|-|}(1, 2.1)(7.283, 2.1)
                    \psline[linecolor=vert]{|-|}(2, 1.8)(8.283, 1.8)
                \end{pspicture}
            \end{center} &
            hello \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The compiler (XeTeX) underlines the line containing the begin of the center environnement around the pspicture environnement. I tried adding braces around this center environnement, but it gaves me the same error.

Can you help me please ? Thanks !

Comment: I didn't know pstricks understands french ;o). What I would do, personally, would be to compile the pstricks figures as standalone files and include the resulting .pdfs  in the tabular environment via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Why do you use `center` environment in a table cell when you specify `c` as alignment specifier with `tabular`?

Comment: the error is `center` not `pstricks` you can not have vertical mode material like `center` in a one-line c column

Comment: Use minipage instead of center environment.

Comment: Ok thanks for all of you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestion of the user @gigair in your comment with a `minipage` you can obtain this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\definecolor{rouge}{rgb}{0.93,0.11,0.14}
\definecolor{vert}{rgb}{0.22,0.71,0.29}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
        \hline
            $\varphi$ &
            \textbf{Chronogrames} &
            \textbf{Lissajous (XY)} \\
        \hline
            $0$ &
             \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
             \psset{xunit=0.5, yunit=0.5}
             \begin{pspicture}(-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)
                    \psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)[$t$,0][$ $,0]
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=rouge, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{2.5*cos(x)}
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=vert, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{1.5*cos(x)}
                    \psline[linecolor=rouge]{|-|}(1, 2.1)(7.283, 2.1)
                    \psline[linecolor=vert]{|-|}(2, 1.8)(8.283, 1.8)
                \end{pspicture}
                \end{minipage}
             &
            hello \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With the value `.5` of `\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}` you can adjust the horizontal cell to put the whole graph into.

Using `tabu` package you can (for example) to have a bit of the space between the graph and the last `\hline` (see `{\tabulinesep=1mm.....}`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\definecolor{rouge}{rgb}{0.93,0.11,0.14}
\definecolor{vert}{rgb}{0.22,0.71,0.29}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
{\tabulinesep=1mm
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
            $\varphi$ &
            \textbf{Chronogrames} &
            \textbf{Lissajous (XY)} \\
        \hline
            $0$ &
             \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
             \psset{xunit=0.5, yunit=0.5}
             \begin{pspicture}(-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)
                    \psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)[$t$,0][$ $,0]
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=rouge, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{2.5*cos(x)}
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=vert, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{1.5*cos(x)}
                    \psline[linecolor=rouge]{|-|}(1, 2.1)(7.283, 2.1)
                    \psline[linecolor=vert]{|-|}(2, 1.8)(8.283, 1.8)
                \end{pspicture}
                \end{minipage}
             &
            hello \\
        \hline
    \end{tabu}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much ! It works now !

Comment: @AdrienMerat Very happy to help you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative, that makes use of a `p` type column, the `shift=*` option of `pspicture` and `\makegapedcells` from the `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\definecolor{rouge}{rgb}{0.93,0.11,0.14}
\definecolor{vert}{rgb}{0.22,0.71,0.29}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\begin{document}
{\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{ | c | p{6.5cm} | c | }
        \hline
            $\varphi$ &
            \textbf{Chronogrames} &
            \textbf{Lissajous (XY)} \\
        \hline
            $0$ &
             \psset{xunit=0.5, yunit=0.5}
             \begin{pspicture}[shift=*](-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)
                    \psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-3.7,-2.5)(3.7, 2.7)[$t$,0][$ $,0]
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=rouge, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{2.5*cos(x)}
                    \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=vert, plotpoints=200]{0}{9}{1.5*cos(x)}
                    \psline[linecolor=rouge]{|-|}(1, 2.1)(7.283, 2.1)
                    \psline[linecolor=vert]{|-|}(2, 1.8)(8.283, 1.8)
                \end{pspicture}
             &
            hello \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't like an answer with 0 score when it is correct and nice.